# MSWORD2016: How do I force Table of Contents to identify a custom style as a heading?

Tags: ms-word

I started with the **minimalist** table of contents title style, in other words based on the **ToC Heading** template. The important aspect is this template creates a vertical bar to the left of the title (picture below).

I would like to reproduce this for all of my headings throughout my document. My conundrum is the following:

1. As the base style is **ToC Heading** and not **Heading 1**, the table of contents will not reference it.
2. When I modify the base style from **ToC Heading** to **Heading 1**, the table of contents will naturally reference it; however, the vertical bar to the left of the title name is lost, as **Heading 1** does not include this bar.

In other words, I want to keep the vertical bar, but it seems that *only* a **ToC Heading** base includes this aesthetic.

#### Picture (vertical bar can be seen in the document; style is based on ToC Heading)

---

[image]

---

How can I either force the table of contents to recognize my custom style as a heading to reference, or how can I retain the same aesthetic in my custom style after switching to a **Heading 1** base?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

1. Highlight existing table of contents (highlighting the ToC title will create a menu above and to the left. Clicking on the ":" will highlight everything).
2. Click reference tab, look at the icon to add a table of contents, and click the arrow for a drop down menu.
3. Select custom table of contents from here.
4. Go to format. My custom style appeared there. I selected 1 as its heading level. It is now treated the same as Heading 1.
5. Add this table of contents and check the option to replace the current table.

Hope that helps someone else!